# How to uninstall a program for a specific user in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exe, uninstallation

I have a program which is installed just for one user. I need to uninstall it through a PowerShell script.

The program is installed on my machine by another application installer called Manager. Now, there is a need to exclude this program installation from the installation of the Manager.

Every other program is installed in the Program Files, only this one is at the location: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

I'm using InnoSetup for these installers. The program is an exe, not msi.

I tried to uninstall it with the following lines:

```
$MyApp = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "Program Name"}
$MyApp.Uninstall()
```

But it throws an exception:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\MinaMaras\Desktop\uninstallreports.ps1:3 char:1
$MyApp.Uninstall()
```

When I run the command

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name`

It doesn't list it there. I guess this is because it is not installed for the machine but for the specific user.

I appreaciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Can you share more info on this "program" that you have installed?  Not all programs behave in the standard (MS-Windows™) way, so it's impossible to answer this ([off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?!) question without that information.

Comment: Sorry, but: ".. by another application installer called Manager" is not very helpful.  There might be a lot of application that have the same name, and (all?) behave different.

Comment: Start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  You may want to change folders to C:\Users\MinaMaras\Desktop before running.

Comment: If `Manager` installed the program, ask `Manager` about uninstalling. `Get-WmiObject` is deprecated and not available in PowerShell Core. Use `Get-CimInstance`.

Comment: When you say "The program is an exe, but msi", do you mean the installer is an MSI?

Comment: @KG-DROID I meant to say the installer is exe file not an MSI

Comment: Does the exe have a silent switch for the uninstall like -Uninst or something?

Comment: Login script...